# Look for office files

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Such as ---- [doc.docx.xls.xlsx.ppt.pptx.pdf], just like the following code. But the query results only pdf.doc.xls, not others, and I am quite confused. I find a lot of answers are not what I want

```
private void doSearch() {
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE};

    String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ? "
            + " or " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ? "
            + " or " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ? "
            + " or " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ? "
            + " or " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ? "
            + " or " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ? "
            + " or " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ? ";

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
            "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
            "application/msword",
            "application/pdf",
            "application/vnd.ms-excel"};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED + " desc");

    String fileName;
    String filePath;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE));
        fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE));
        filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA));
        Log.e("ryze_text", fileName + " -- " + type + "--" + filePath);//Here is the result

    }

    cursor.close();
    cursor = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day,I found an alternative method.Look at the log first

I changed the two parameters to null to indicate a full search

```
getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
            projection,
//                selection,
//                selectionArgs,
            null,null,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED + " desc");
```

---

```
Log.e("ryze_text", fileName + " -- " + type + "--" + filePath);
```

Use the above code, I got the following log

```
20160423.xlsx -- null--/storage/emulated/0/tencent/MicroMsg/Download/20160423.xlsx
```

I do not know why mimeType is null,But i can already get what i want pptx, xlsx, docx.

Comment: That returns **all** the files, not just the listed ones

Comment: Yes, now I can only filter the suffix in the results, get the file I want